# Netbean: how to resize the UI Window to screen Size

Tags: java, swing, jframe, jwindow

I am developing a small application in Java using Netbeans. I use a JFrame as a base control and drag and drop all required controls over it as appropriate.

The application is working fine as expect. Now i simply want that when my application runs for the fist time the size of my Application window should be equal to the size of my screen. In simple words i want my application to be maximized when it opens. Following is the code for my main method:

```
public static void main(String args[]) {
        java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {

            public void run() {
                MyUI myframe = new MyUI();
                myframe.setTitle("my tiltle");
                myframe.setVisible(true);                
                //new GPrideUI().setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }
```

Comment: Again, as long as you are asking a question regarding coding (which you are) the IDE (Netbeans) is completely irrelevant, and I actually find it rare that the IDE is involved in solving the problem!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

See [`Frame.setExtendedState(int)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/Frame.html#setExtendedState-int-) which:

> Sets the state of this frame. The state is represented as a bitwise mask.
>
> - `NORMAL` Indicates that no state bits are set.
> - `ICONIFIED`
> - `MAXIMIZED_HORIZ`
> - `MAXIMIZED_VERT`
> - `MAXIMIZED_BOTH` Concatenates `MAXIMIZED_HORIZ` and `MAXIMIZED_VERT`.

Answer (score 0):

```
private void formWindowOpened(java.awt.event.WindowEvent evt) {                                  
     this.setExtendedState(this.getExtendedState()|JFrame.MAXIMIZED_BOTH);
}
```

You Only need to do this.